# How can I list items with part of the list right justified?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lists

I have an appendix title page on which I want to list all the different appendices neatly. Here is the code I have for it:

```
\documentclass[letter,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\vfill

\LARGE\rmfamily\bfseries\centering APPENDICES

\noindent\textcolor{complement2}{\rule{0.75\textwidth}{2mm}}\par

\Large
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Appendix A\hfill CFD Results \\
    \item Appendix B\hfill Pump and Inlet Pipe Specifications\\
    \item Appendix C\hfill Technical Drawings \\
    \item Appendix D\hfill Cost Breakdown \\
    \item Appendix E\hfill Some super other different thing\\
\end{enumerate}

\vfill

\end{document}
```

Essentially, I want to separate 'Appendix X' and 'Title' with `\hfill`. However, the text overlaps as you can see and spreads to the next line. [image]

How do I make 'Specifications' right-justify?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer what would I use instead?

Comment: How do I create a special ToC? I already have one in my main document, so need to be able to separate the appendix ToC from the main ToC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can emulate an `enumerate` environment inside a `tabularx` environment:

```
\documentclass[letter,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\vfill

\LARGE\rmfamily\bfseries\centering APPENDICES

\noindent\textcolor{Peru!90}{\rule{0.75\textwidth}{2mm}}\par
\vspace{\dimexpr\baselineskip + \topsep\relax}
\Large
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.4}
\newcounter{tabenum}\setcounter{tabenum}{0}
\newcommand{\tabitem}{\stepcounter{tabenum}\,\thetabenum.\hspace{\labelsep}}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X@{}}
    \tabitem Appendix A & CFD Results \\
    \tabitem Appendix B & Pump and Inlet Pipe Specifications\\
    \tabitem Appendix C & Technical Drawings \\
    \tabitem Appendix D & Cost Breakdown \\
    \tabitem Appendix E & Some super other different thing
\end{tabularx}
\vfill

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Added:**

Another (semantically cleaner) possibility consists in using the partial table of contents capabilities nof the `titletoc` package: at the beginning of the appendix, you can use the command, say,

```
\appendix
\startcontents[appendices]
  \section{CFD Results}
     …  
  \section{Some  super other different thing}
\stopcontents[appendices]
```

and print it wherever you please with the command:

```
\printcontents[appendices]{Appendix}{1}{}
```

Comment: Above @ChristianHupfer indicated I should be careful defining the list of appendices as I may have typos in it (should I change the names of the appendices). As a workaround to this, I made a few definitions in my preamble:
`\def \appendixA {CFD Results}`
and so on, then replaced anywhere in the code I actually typed "CFD Results" with `\appendixA`. If I have to change the appendix titles I will just do so in the preamble.

Comment: That's an excellent suggestion.